# How do I get Math.random function to update every time the property it is assigned to is called?

Tags: javascript, math, random

I am working in Javascript and building a die roller function that would be called by various properties within an object. Alone, the rollDice function works properly, but within the object the random number generated by rollDice stays the same (unless I refresh the page). How do I get the rollDice function to update every time the property is called?

For instance, if I type `rollDice(1, 6)` in the console I get a random number between 1 and 6. When I repeatedly type `rollDice(1, 6)`, I get different numbers. Then, if I type `availableWeapons.kick`, which should be the same as `rollDice(1, 6)`, I get a random number between 1 and 6. When I repeatedly type `availableWeapons.kick`, I do not get different numbers...I get the same number over and over again. When I refresh the page, that random number for `availableWeapons.kick` will be different.

Thanks for your help!

```
// Dice
function rollDice(numDice, sides){
    var result = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < numDice; i++) {
        var diceRoll = Math.floor(Math.random() * sides) + 1;
        result += diceRoll;
    };
    return result;
};

// Weapons
const availableWeapons = {
    fist: rollDice(1, 3),
    kick: rollDice(1, 6),
    headButt: rollDice(1, 4),
    epee: rollDice(1, 6) + 1,
    revolver45: rollDice(1, 10) + 2,
    gauge12: rollDice(4, 6)
};
```

Comment: Think about what your code does: it sets object properties to the result of calling `rollDice` at the *time of initialization*. But that's not what you want; you want it to call `rollDice` *each time* the object property is accessed. There are multiple ways this could be fixed.

Comment: Check this code out this will give you the [idea](https://js.do/code/523251) . But AKX and Dave is correct . :)

Answer (score 3):

As things are, you are generating the values exactly once and assigning them into the object, so it'll look like

```
{ fist: 2, kick: 5, ... }
```

in-memory.

You can wrap each property into an anonymous arrow function:

```
// Weapons
const availableWeapons = {
  fist: () => rollDice(1, 3),
  kick: () => rollDice(1, 6),
  headButt: () => rollDice(1, 4),
  epee: () => rollDice(1, 6) + 1,
  revolver45: () => rollDice(1, 10) + 2,
  gauge12: () => rollDice(4, 6),
};
```

Then you can roll new values by calling the functions, e.g.

```
availableWeapons.headButt()
availableWeapons.headButt()
availableWeapons.headButt()
```

If you'd need a new object with all values rolled, you can write a function such as

```
function rollAll(rollObject) {
  const rolls = {};
  Object.keys(rollObject).forEach(key => {
    let value = rollObject[key];
    if(typeof value === "function") {
      value = value();  // call all functions
    }
    rolls[key] = value;
  });
  return rolls;
}
```

-- passing that function an object that contains functions (and it may also contain "bare" values) will return a new object with all rolls.